# Parsing unresolved requirement Eclipse 2021-03 error

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, tycho

I'm trying to build an RCP application on Eclipse 2021-03 and I'm encountering the following issue:

```
[ERROR] Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Bundle my.company.plugin cannot be resolved:my.company.plugin [85]
[ERROR]   Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui; version="2.0.0"
[ERROR]     -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui"; bundle-version="2.7.0.v20210114-1216"; version="2.6.0"
[ERROR]        org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui [7]
[ERROR]          Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui; bundle-version="3.107.0"
[ERROR]            -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui; bundle-version="3.119.0.v20210111-1350"; singleton:="true"
[ERROR]               org.eclipse.ui [1]
[ERROR]                 Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.workbench; bundle-version="[3.120.0,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
[ERROR]                   -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui.workbench; bundle-version="3.122.101.v20210423-1001"; singleton:="true"
[ERROR]                      org.eclipse.ui.workbench [80]
[ERROR]                        Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal
[ERROR]                          -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.e4.core.commands"; bundle-version="0.13.0.v20201119-1132"; version="0.0.0"; x-friends:="org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings,org.eclipse.ui.workbench"
[ERROR]                             org.eclipse.e4.core.commands [32]
[ERROR]                               Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.e4.core.services.log
[ERROR]                                 -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.e4.core.services.log; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.e4.core.services"; bundle-version="2.2.600.v20210110-1654"; version="0.0.0"; x-friends:="org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings,  org.eclipse.e4.ui.services,  org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench,  org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt,  org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt,  org.eclipse.ui.workbench,  org.eclipse.e4.core.commands"
[ERROR]                                    org.eclipse.e4.core.services [36]
[ERROR]                                      Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.extender; filter:="(&(osgi.extender=osgi.component)(version>=1.2)(!(version>=2.0)))"
[ERROR]                        Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench
[ERROR]                          -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench"; bundle-version="1.12.100.v20210122-1731"; version="0.0.0"; x-friends:="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.fragment,  org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt,  org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt,  org.eclipse.ui.workbench,  org.eclipse.ui.ide.application,  org.eclipse.ui.ide,  org.eclipse.e4.emf.xpath.test"
[ERROR]                             org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench [55]
[ERROR]                               Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench; bundle-version="1.2.0"
[ERROR]                                 -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench; bundle-version="2.1.1000.v20210111-0958"; singleton:="true"
[ERROR]                                    org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench [53]
[ERROR]                                      Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.e4.core.services; bundle-version="0.9.0"
[ERROR]                                        -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.e4.core.services; bundle-version="2.2.600.v20210110-1654"; singleton:="true"
[ERROR]                               Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.e4.ui.services; bundle-version="0.9.0"
[ERROR]                                 -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.e4.ui.services; bundle-version="1.5.0.v20210115-1333"; singleton:="true"
[ERROR]                                    org.eclipse.e4.ui.services [46]
[ERROR]                                      Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.e4.core.services; bundle-version="0.9.0"
[ERROR]                                        -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.e4.core.services; bundle-version="2.2.600.v20210110-1654"; singleton:="true"
[ERROR]                               Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.e4.core.services; bundle-version="0.9.0"
[ERROR]                                 -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.e4.core.services; bundle-version="2.2.600.v20210110-1654"; singleton:="true"
[ERROR]                        Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.addons
[ERROR]                          -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.addons; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench"; bundle-version="1.12.100.v20210122-1731"; version="0.0.0"; x-internal:="true"
[ERROR]                        Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.e4.core.commands
[ERROR]                          -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.e4.core.commands; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.e4.core.commands"; bundle-version="0.13.0.v20201119-1132"; version="0.0.0"; x-friends:="org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings,  org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench,  org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt,  org.eclipse.ui.workbench,  org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt,  org.eclipse.e4.ui.progress,  org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.tests"
[ERROR]          Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.security.ui; bundle-version="[1.0.0,2.0.0)"
[ERROR]            -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.equinox.security.ui; bundle-version="1.3.0.v20210121-0947"; singleton:="true"
[ERROR]               org.eclipse.equinox.security.ui [75]
[ERROR]                 Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui; bundle-version="[3.4.0,4.0.0)"
[ERROR]                   -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui; bundle-version="3.119.0.v20210111-1350"; singleton:="true"
[ERROR]   Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui
[ERROR]     -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui; bundle-version="3.119.0.v20210111-1350"; singleton:="true"
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

I have Eclipse 2021-03 as the target platform and Java 11 set. I'm not sure why the Eclipse dependency is not being recognized. I've gone through all the plugins/ imports mentioned in the error and I don't see anything missing or would cause this error. I've also built this same application on Photon without any issues.

Any pointers or suggestions on parsing this error would be helpful.

Comment: The `Require-Capability: osgi.extender` line makes me think you may not have the `org.apache.felix.scr` plug-in included which provides that capability.